Consolide NAS drive data but maintaining earliest creation date
Scenario:
I have about a dozen USB and NAS drives that were used over the years to back up various PCs. A lot of data was migrated from USB to multiple NAS drives during this time.
I’ve tried several duplicate file removal tools, but they’ve all been cumbersome and don’t meet my needs, especially when it comes to preserving the original directory dates. While I can copy individual files manually using Linux to maintain the old dates, I’m looking for a more automated solution that works in Windows.
What I Need:
Hash-Based Duplicate Detection: I need a powerful tool that can run a hash table scan across all USB and NAS drives connected to our server. The goal is to identify duplicate files and directories across these storage devices.
Directory Sync and Rebuild: The tool should be able to:
Identify duplicate directory structures (e.g., C:/foo/pickle/accounting/invoices/backups/) and find all similar or identical structures across the drives.
Sync and rebuild these file structures, consolidating data while retaining the original directory and file creation dates.
File Consolidation:
For identical files with different timestamps, I want to delete newer copies from the old trees and retain the original versions with their original dates.
If an employee has added new files deep within a newer copy of a directory, I need those files moved to the rebuilt structure so that we end up with one consolidated tree that contains all the new and old content.
Preserving Metadata: The key requirement is that the tool must not alter the original file and directory creation dates. My users rely on the historical context, so I can’t have data from 2012 suddenly showing a 2024 date.
Most duplicate removal software either rebuilds new trees but loses the original dates, or removes duplicate trees entirely without preserving critical metadata. I need a solution that can do both: consolidate duplicate directories and preserve all original timestamps.
